# .NET 6.0 upgrade gives System.TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, wix, .net-6.0, .net-assembly

Currently in my Solution all the components are in .net standard and .net framework, due to some requirement one component we have migrated to .net 6 , then during instalation of artifacts I am getting `System.TypeLoadException`  in event viewer.

during migration of .net 6 we have maid some changes in WiX projects

```
<Component Id="_COMP_Process_Executor_exe" Guid="{0D8D84F1-FFC5-2856-F1D7-8620DA17313B}">
   <File Id="_FILE_Process_Executor_exe" Name="Process.Executor.exe" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Process.Executor.exe" />
</Component>
```

since we migrated this application to .net 6 we removed `Assembly` and `AssemblyManifest` from this particular component.

Comment: What is the exact exception message incl. stacktrace? Please note that .NET assemblies cannot load/reference .NET Framework assemblies and .NET Framework assemblies cannot load/reference .NET assemblies. If a project needs to be referenced by .NET and .NET Framework you need to make it multi-target so that two assemblies get generated – one for .NET and one for .NET Framework.

Comment: both are different assembly which is there in the artifacts while installing it i am getting unable to load exception.

Comment: Application: Interop.AdminAgent.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.TypeLoadException
   at Interop.AdminAgent.Program.Main()

Comment: @ckuri this exception i got while checking in event viewer is there any way I can find which assembly couldn't load  ?

Comment: The type and assembly that failed to load should be mentioned in the EventViewer log entry. What happens when you start in the application in Visual Studio? It should stop at the exception and show you the details.

Comment: when I Start visual studio it works fine , i got this exception only during installing of the artfacts(.exe) file